# Sending email through my hotmail account and changing the 'from'

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

I build a web form on my website to allow visitors to send me a message. Something very basic (for my personal use). On my backend (c# .Net MVC) I use **SmtpClient** to send the mail. I use my hotmail account for that purpose. It works. Please note that `from` is equal to the username used in `Credentials`.

```
        SmtpClient _client = new SmtpClient();
        _client.Host = "smtp.live.com";
        _client.Port = 587;
        _client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        _client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ttttt@hotmail.com", "mypassword");
        _client.EnableSsl = true;
        _client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("ttttt@gmail.com");
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ttttt@hotmail.com");
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

        mail.Subject = "The subject";
        mail.Body = "The message";
        _client.Send(mail);
```

When I receive the mail, the sender is equal to the receiver ( myself :) This is not ideal.

- From: **John Doe**
- To: **John Doe**
- Subject: **My subject**
- Message: **My message**

I would prefer having the visitor's email address in the sender (the `from`). So I try to change that but it doesn't work. I got the error message below:

*System.Net.Mail.SmtpException Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.*

**I understand** that this is not working for security reason. I cannot send an email 'in the name of' someone else.

Before giving up, I come here in the hope of someone can suggest me an alternative.

PS: I know I can use `mail.ReplyToList.Add(emailofvisitor);` then when I press `Reply` this is the visitor's email which is used but this is not still ideal because I still see my `ttttt@hotmail.com` in the `from` field.

Comment: Its bad. Don't travel the dark road. Just have a sender like "contactform@domain.com" and put the users mail in the subject or replyTo address. Putting their name in the "from" address implies stuff that might not have happend.

Comment: As an alternative you could just expose your wmaol address and let them use it ;-)

Comment: I know it is ugly, but if it is only about optics you could just use `DisplayName` to change what you see.

Comment: Thank you. You are probably right !

Comment: Thanks @Barns for your suggestion but as you said... this is ugly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hope I didn't misunderstand your request, I'm assuming you would like to change the displayed name for the sender, this is what I do in my project, Add the following to your Web.Config or App.Config file:
Fill the from part with whatever you want and it will show it as the sender name.

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="YourDisplayName &lt;YourEmail&gt;" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" host="hostname" port="587" userName="yourusername" password="yourpassword"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

C# code:

```
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(smtpSection.From);
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("youremail@gmail.com");
                message.To.Add(to);
                message.Subject = "The subject";
                message.Body = "The message";
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.Send(message);
```